# Unable to stop Foxit reader installing itself continuously

Tags: windows, foxit-reader

I have Windows 10 with build 19043.1110 and problem with Foxit Reader's version 10.11. It keeps trying to install itself automatically, continuously and endlessly in the background all the time. Installation always fails, because it prompts me that I have already newer version installed (v.11.0.0).

I've tried to uninstall ***all*** the Foxit Reader versions, erase ***all*** the Foxit **files** and **Windows registry settings** related to Foxit Reader via RevoUninstaller and stop the Foxit Reader installation **Windows service** manually and also stop it from starting itself after boot, but it still just keeps spawning back always automatically! How can I stop this endless loop?? Thanks.

Comment: Try using [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) to find the installation startup.

Comment: I have no idea what build you are running but it's not `49893` the highest build number for Windows 10 is 19043.  Your question is confusing since Foxit Reader is third-party software.  It almost sounds like you are connected to a company network, and the Administrator of the machine is installing it automatically (there is also software that allows that to be trivial).

Comment: @Richie79 - We are not a forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The poster affirmed that the problem was fixed using
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
to find the rogue startup.

But it came back ...

The next tool to use was
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)
and drag the bull's-eye and drop it over the displayed message.
This found the process that issued the installation message.

Double-click on the process displayed its name and originating
folder. Once it was located, the solution was simple.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but this thread has been edited for the worse! All the relevant and helpful answers has been erased! Autoruns did **NOT** solve this problem. **@harrymc** helped me finding the correct solution and the key was to utilize free MS SysInternal's Process Explorer by "bull's eyeing" the Foxit Reader prompts to find the actual file which was causing the endless loop of installation prompts. Deleting the culprit file ended the prompts. In case anyone else encounters anything similar, then utilize free MS SysInternal's Process Explorer to "bulls eye" the prompt windows.

Comment: Some moderator decided our comments were superfluous and deleted everything. I added it into my answer.